# Improve lock process in ASP.net core

Tags: c#, multithreading, asp.net-core, .net-core, locking

How can I improve the lock process in the following function?

This function adds the web sockets of users of each page of a site to the lists in a static dictionary

```
public void Add(TKey key, CustomServerWebSocket customWebSocket)
{
    _customWebSocketsLock.EnterWriteLock();

    try
    {
        if (!_customWebSockets.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            _customWebSockets.TryAdd(key, new CustomServerWebSockets());
        }

        _customWebSockets[key].Add(customWebSocket);
    }
    finally
    {
        _customWebSocketsLock.ExitWriteLock();
    }
}
```

To make the issue clearer, pay attention to the two classes related to this function.

CustomServerWebSockets contains CustomWebSockets:

```
public sealed class CustomServerWebSockets : IDisposable
{
    private readonly ReaderWriterLockSlim _customWebSocketsLock = new();
    private readonly List<CustomServerWebSocket> _customWebSockets = new();
    private bool _disposed;

    public void Add(CustomServerWebSocket customWebSocket)
    {
        _customWebSocketsLock.EnterWriteLock();

        try
        {
            _customWebSockets.Add(customWebSocket);
        }
        finally
        {
            _customWebSocketsLock.ExitWriteLock();
        }
    }

    public void Remove(CustomServerWebSocket socket)
    {
        _customWebSocketsLock.EnterWriteLock();

        try
        {
            _customWebSockets.Remove(socket);
        }
        finally
        {
            _customWebSocketsLock.ExitWriteLock();
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_disposed)
        {
            return;
        }

        _disposed = true;

        _customWebSocketsLock.Dispose();
    }

    //...
}
```

WebSocketsOrganizer contains CustomServerWebSockets:

```
public sealed class WebSocketsOrganizer<TKey> : IDisposable where TKey : notnull
{
    private readonly ReaderWriterLockSlim _customWebSocketsLock = new();
    private readonly Dictionary<TKey, CustomServerWebSockets> _customWebSockets = new();
    private bool _disposed;

    //The function in question
    public void Add(TKey key, CustomServerWebSocket customWebSocket)
    {
        _customWebSocketsLock.EnterWriteLock();

        try
        {
            if (!_customWebSockets.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                _customWebSockets.TryAdd(key, new CustomServerWebSockets());
            }

            _customWebSockets[key].Add(customWebSocket);
        }
        finally
        {
            _customWebSocketsLock.ExitWriteLock();
        }
    }

    public void Remove(TKey key, CustomServerWebSocket customWebSocket)
    {
        _customWebSocketsLock.EnterReadLock();

        try
        {
            if (!_customWebSockets.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                return;
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            _customWebSocketsLock.ExitReadLock();
        }

        _customWebSocketsLock.EnterWriteLock();

        try
        {
            if (!_customWebSockets.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                return;
            }

            _customWebSockets[key].Remove(customWebSocket);

            if (!_customWebSockets[key].Any())
            {
                _customWebSockets.Remove(key);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            _customWebSocketsLock.ExitWriteLock();
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_disposed)
        {
            return;
        }

        _disposed = true;

        _customWebSocketsLock.Dispose();
    }

    //...
}
```

Comment: Erm maybe `lock (someObject) { ...  }` although holding websockets like this looks a bit messy in terms of memory management and disposal.

Comment: As a side note you can improve the performance slightly by using the [`TryGetValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.trygetvalue) instead of doing double work with the `ContainsKey` and then the indexer.

Comment: I understand my confusion now. I didn't notice that `CustomServerWebSockets` is a collection of `CustomServerWebSocket`. Didn't see that `s` in the end.

Comment: Any reason why you use your own classes instead of classes already existing in .Net such as `ConcurrentDictionary`, for instance?

Comment: To improve the lock process in the given function, you can use the lock statement instead of ReaderWriterLockSlim. 
publicvoidAdd(TKey key, CustomServerWebSocket customWebSocket)
{
lock(_customWebSocketsLock)"
if(!_customWebSockets.ContainsKey(key))
another you can try is asynchronous locking mechanisms that are more efficient and scalable than traditional locks.Using AsyncLock allows multiple asynchronous operations to execute concurrently while ensuring that the critical section of code is accessed by only one thread at a time.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following function works better than the prototype

```
public void Add(TKey key, CustomServerWebSocket customWebSocket)
{
    _customWebSocketsLock.EnterReadLock();

    try
    {
        _customWebSockets.TryGetValue(key, out var customWebSockets);

        if (customWebSockets is not null)
        {
            customWebSockets.Add(customWebSocket);

            return;
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        _customWebSocketsLock.ExitReadLock();
    }

    _customWebSocketsLock.EnterWriteLock();

    try
    {
        if (!_customWebSockets.ContainsKey(key))
        {
            _customWebSockets.TryAdd(key, new CustomServerWebSockets());
        }

        _customWebSockets[key].Add(customWebSocket);
    }
    finally
    {
        _customWebSocketsLock.ExitWriteLock();
    }
}
```

Comment: Changing the contents of collections inside a readlock seems like a recipe for disaster

Comment: customWebSockets also benefits from a locking mechanism

Comment: Seeing the updated question, this might actually be fine. At least I do not see immediately how this could fail. The system does not let me take away my downvote, sorry about that.